# Using the Vimeo api gives intermittent ssl error when getting video list

Tags: php, curl, https, rhel, vimeo-api

I am having issues using the PHP API [here](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#troubleshooting). It works but every 2nd or 3rd request I get the following error:

> Unable to complete request.[SSL connect error]

This is happening on Vimeo.php:154. This is right after curl has executed. I tried using curl on its own at the command line and have gotten:

> curl: (35) SSL connect error

This references:

> A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.

So I tried it with PHP file_get_contents and the warning I get is

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer

I am kind of at a loss for where this comming from and don't know if this is VImeo rejecting my request sometimes or the server losing the connection sometimes. I am trying to find out if someone has had this issue before or has some steps I can use to go about getting more of a clue as to what is causing the issue. Here is my code

Using file_Gets_contents

```
$opts = array(
                'http'=>array(
                        'method'=>"GET",
                        'header'=>"Authorization: bearer <Personal access token>\r\n"
                ),
                'ssl'=>array(
                        'allow_self_signed'=>false,
                        'verify_peer'=>false,
                )
        );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$userAccount = '<user account>';
$url = "https://api.vimeo.com/users/$userAccount/videos";
$unparsed_json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$json_object = json_decode($unparsed_json);
var_dump($json_object);die();
```

Using CURL

```
$userAccount = '<user account>';
$url = "https://api.vimeo.com/users/$userAccount/videos";
$curlHeader = [
    'Authorization: bearer <Personal access token>',
    'Accept: ' . self::VERSION_STRING,
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$unparsed_json = curl_exec ($ch);
// Check if any error occurred
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    var_dump('Curl error: ', curl_error($ch), ' Curl error no: ', curl_errno($ch), ' Unparsed json: ', $unparsed_json, ' Info: ', $info, 'DIR CERT: ', __DIR__ . '/CERT'); die();
}
curl_close ($ch);
$json_object = json_decode($unparsed_json);
var_dump($unparsed_json);die();
```

Using Vimeo.php

```
$userAccount = '<user account>';
$url = "https://api.vimeo.com/users/$userAccount/videos";
$client_id = '<Client ID>';
$client_secret = '<Secret>';
$lib = new Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);

$lib->setToken('<Personal access token>');
$response = $lib->request($url, [], 'GET');
var_dump($response['body']);die();
```

I used verbose on curl at the Linux command line and saw this:

> About to connect() to api.vimeo.com port 443 (#0)
>   Trying 104.156.85.217... connected
>   Connected to api.vimeo.com (104.156.85.217) port 443 (#0)
>   Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
>   CAfile: 'cert file location' 
>   CApath: none 
>   NSS error -5961 
>   Closing connection #0
>   SSL connect error
>   curl: (35) SSL connect error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue was that the web filter was blocking. The way I found out was using openssl directly:

> [username@server username]$ openssl s_client -connect :443 -msg
>       CONNECTED(00000003)
>       '>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00f4], ClientHello
>       **write:errno=104**
>       ---
>       no peer certificate available
>       ---
>       No client certificate CA names sent
>       ---
>       SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 249 bytes
>       ---
>       New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
>       Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
>       Compression: NONE
>       Expansion: NONE
>       ---

Comment: Which web filter are you talking about? One at vimeo, or on your network? I'm getting the same intermittent error.

Comment: This was a web filter on the network on our end that was blocking.

Comment: how we can fix that issue??